# Can R download a .xlsx from Sharepoint with username/password?

Tags: r, sharepoint, rcurl, httr

I need to download a sheet from an excel file into a dataframe in R to support a flexdashboard in development.  It needs to be automated, so downloading the file local and then accessing it isn't an option.

I was able to make the sharepoint connection and download data using getBinaryURL(), but couldn't get a specific sheet obviously.  I turned the sheet into a .csv just to troubleshoot more and was able to get readable data in a single character vector with this code:

```
library(RCurl)
require(httr)

pwd<-as.raw(c(...))
url <- "https://URL"

destfile<-"C:\\Destpath"
data<-rawToChar(getBinaryURL(url,userpwd = paste0("user", ":", 
        rawToChar(pwd)),ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
```

What came out on the other end was a lot of this:

```
"$-   , $-   , $-   , $-   \r\nPSU, $-   , $-   , $-   ,3,0,0.003,0,0.09,1,0.9, $-   ,4800, $-   , $-   ,4800, $-   , $-   , $-   , $-   ,4800,1811367.812, $-   ,462000, $-   ,24485735.68, $-   , $-   ,"
```

I tried to push that into a dataframe using

```
data.frame(data,sep=","header=TRUE)
```

but it just spit back out the same output as before.

Is there way way to just easily retrieve the excel file when username/password is required using just R?

Comment: Try `read.csv(text=data, sep=",", header=FALSE)`. But this is not a normal CSV (sans headers): your first row has 4 columns, but the second row appears to have 28 columns. It might help to see a sample of the original content.

Comment: That was a copy/paste from the middle of the data...the csv frame is 28 x 16 with text headers.  If it helps, the printout has "\r\n" is at the end of each record with commas delineating in each record.  Is there some way to just cut to a new record for each instance of "\r\n"?

Comment: `strsplit(data, "[\r\n]+")` will return a list with one "line" per list element. It sounds like your data is not a simple table, so reading into a frame may not be the best way to go. What about `read.csv(text=data, header=TRUE)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Ah, see my newness let me forget simple things like strsplit().  I ran strsplit and *then* read.csv(...) and it worked perfectly.  Thank you a ton for the help

Comment: Even better, it worked perfectly with read.csv(...) without strsplit.  Thanks again.

Comment: Turns out I was way overthinking it and solved it without needing login by running:
'url2<- "//internal.sharepoint.address.xlsx"
'model_Data<-read_excel(url2,sheet="Sheet")